# React Router Wrapped in a BottomNavigation not loading the new component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

I can not for the life of me figure out how to load the DMO page from a `BottomNavigation` component. Going to `"/dom"` works perfectly. Clicking the buttons does not work at all. The initial `"/"` loads great. Thoughts? Suggestions?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import BottomNavigation from '@mui/material/BottomNavigation';
import BottomNavigationAction from '@mui/material/BottomNavigationAction';
import AccountTreeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountTree';
import DatasetLinkedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DatasetLinked';
import LogoutIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Logout';
import './navigation.css'
import {createBrowserRouter, Link, RouterProvider} from 'react-router-dom';
import PmoTable from "../PmoTable/PmoTable";
import DMO from "../DMO/DMO";

export default function Navigation() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <PmoTable />,
    },
    {
      path: "dmo",
      element: <DMO />,
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <Box className="navBar">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
      <BottomNavigation
        showLabels
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
      >
        <BottomNavigationAction label="PMO" icon={<AccountTreeIcon />} >
          <Link to='/'></Link>
        </BottomNavigationAction>
        <BottomNavigationAction label="DMO" icon={<DatasetLinkedIcon />} >
          <Link to='/dmo'></Link>
        </BottomNavigationAction>
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Logout" icon={<LogoutIcon />} >
          <Link to='/logout'></Link>
        </BottomNavigationAction>
      </BottomNavigation>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BottomNavigation`, or more specifically the `Link` components it renders, needs to be rendered within the routing context provided by the `BrowserRouter`. Move the `BottomNavigation` into a layout route component so it can be rendered within the router.

The the `Link` components are also empty which means they have to clickable/interactable area. Rewrite the code to render the `BottomNavigationAction` *as* `Link` components and pass the link props through.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  Link,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navigation() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      element: (
        <>
          <Outlet />
          <BottomNavigation
            showLabels
            value={value}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              setValue(newValue);
            }}
          >
            <BottomNavigationAction
              component={Link}
              label="PMO"
              icon={<AccountTreeIcon />}
              to='/'
            />
            <BottomNavigationAction
              component={Link}
              label="DMO"
              icon={<DatasetLinkedIcon />}
              to='/dmo'
            />
            <BottomNavigationAction
              component={Link}
              label="Logout"
              icon={<LogoutIcon />}
              to="/logout"
            />
          </BottomNavigation>
        </>
      ),
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <PmoTable />,
        },
        {
          path: "dmo",
          element: <DMO />,
        }
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <Box className="navBar">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```